# Best way to modify product collection on list page

Tags: event-observer, product-list, performance, collection-filtering

I've a requirement that I've to modify product listing page and hide all configurable products for which if any of the associated product is out of stock.

Which is the best place to modify considering performance and my filter should be applicable for all attributes?

I know two possible options.

1. list.phtml from template or
2. Create my own observer using catalog_block_product_list_collection event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events are always the best approach.
This way, your changes are independent of the presentation layer (theme). If you have 2 websites with different themes you will have all modifications in one place.
Changing the template file may result in pagination problems.